# Links showing in red instead of blue?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I use the canvas view, my app has normal blue links in both dark and light themes. However, when I run it in the simulator or on any test device, they are red instead of blue, in both light and dark themes. What the heck is going on?!?

I'm using latest version of everything, and I've tried it on multiple sim devices and physical devices. This is present on every screen in my app.

[image: Sim view vs Canvas view]

Comment: How do you render the link? Post the code, please

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my co-developer had added an override in the AppDelegate that was changing the text colors. Removing that fixed the issue.